# Why Raspberry suddenly stopped supporting GUI?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, gui

I have a raspberry pi 3 (model B+) with rasbian OS . Suddenly, after boot I can't get to the desktop interface. Only the command line is supported. I have tested it with another SD card and gui works. So, I concluded that the SD has some problem. I really need all the files and configurations on the raspberry(old/corrupted SD card).

Is there a way I can fix this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Raspberry Pi config by running `raspi-config`.
2. Select `3 Boot Options`.
3. In the submenu, select `B1 Desktop / CLI`
4. Out of the 4 boot options, select the last: `B4 Desktop Autologin`
5. Reboot the Pi.

This should bring back the old behaviour you had, where the GUI will start automatically on boot.

Answer (score -2):

At the command line type `startx`, assuming there are not further issues with the install this will launch the GUI.

Comment: This indeed fixes the issue but only as long as the command is running. Is there a more permanent solution? Thank you